# How to find the summation of phasors in exponential form

Tags: arithmetic

Is there any expression in form of $A e^{j\phi}$ for the following summation:
$A_1 e^{j\phi_1} + A_2 e^{j\phi_2} + ... + A_n e^{j\phi_n}$?

Comment: It is equivalent to adding sinusoids of magnitude $A_i$ and phase $\phi_i$, and all having the same frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very nice one in general, I'm afraid.

We can always express a complex number $z$ in the form $a + ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real. Then $z = re^{i\theta}$, where $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and
$$\theta =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }a = b = 0 \\
\pi/2 & \text{if }a = 0 \text{ and }b > 0 \\
-\pi/2 & \text{if }a = 0 \text{ and }b < 0 \\
\arctan(b/a) & \text{if }a > 0 \\
\arctan(b/a) + \pi & \text{if }a < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

Now
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k e^{i\phi_k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k (\cos(\phi_k) + i\sin(\phi_k))\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k \cos(\phi_k) + i \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k \sin(\phi_k) \\
\end{aligned}$$
so we can set
$$a = \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k \cos(\phi_k)$$
and
$$b = \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k \sin(\phi_k)$$
and plug into the above formulas for $r$ and $\theta$.